# How to add helper class function in twig template with laravel

Tags: laravel, twig

in blade template I have used like:

```
{{ Helper::getName() }}
```

But how it is used with twig template?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call PHP function from Twig template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665923/call-php-function-from-twig-template)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [laravel-twigbridge](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-twigbridge) you can use helpers from default Extensions, e.g:

```
{{ form_open(...) }}
```

instead of

{{ Form::open(...) }}

See [docs](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-twigbridge#extensions)