# What would the TWIG equivalent of <?php the_field('field_name'); ?> be?

Tags: php, twig

I'm using Wordpress with the ["Advanced Custom Fields" plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/), and I'm trying to call variables from the plugin into my TWIG file.

[The documentation for the plugin](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/) says to use `<?php the_field('field_name'); ?>` in the PHP, but I can't figure out how to translate that code to TWIG.

**I tried the following:**

- Running code as is (but it appears TWIG doesn't run pure PHP.)
- `{% post.the_field('my_fields_name') %}`, but to no avail
- `{{ post.my_fields_name }}`, but it printed/logged "Array" to the frontend.
- `{{ post.get_field('the_field', my_fields_name) }}` and
  `{{ post.get_field('the_field', 'my_fields_name') }}`

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18667961/2518525) is worth a read. Basically states that you can't call php function directly, however you can write extensions of TWIG to do this

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while, but ended up being an easy solution! Turns out these custom fields are stored in the meta-data, so all I had to do was `{{ post.meta('my_fields_name') }}`