# How to create an extension using Twig

Tags: php, twig

I am running apache and php on Ubuntu 17.04
I am using twig. I installed Twig like this.

```
cd /var/www/html/my-new-website
composer install twig/twig
composer require twig/twig
```

At this point the way I have been using Twig is: first I create a php file and do some stuff, create an array and render the template with the array data. Next I have separated sections of my page and put them in templates.

here is an example index.php that creates an array of directories then renders it with the files.html.twig located in the templates directory.

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => 'cache',
));

$dir = "path/to/dir";
$exclude = array( ".","..",".*","index.php" );
$files = array_diff(scandir($dir), $exclude);

/*
echo ''; print_r($files);
*/

$template = $twig->loadTemplate('files.html.twig');
echo $template->render(['files' => $files]);
?>
```

here is the files.html.twig, it extends "base.html.twig"

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}
My Directory Listing
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% for file in files %}
      <li><a href="{{ file | url_encode }}">{{ file }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

and the base.html.twig contains main wrapper with navbar and footer. This all works as expected.

Right now I have the navbar in my base.html.twig, it is just html where I have to edit the items.

I have made a php function to get the navbar array that works in a template(navbar.html.twig), but the problem is I have to put or include this php function in each page I create. I want my navbar.html.twig template to get the array from the php funtion directly.

I believe I need to create a twig extension(php function) and register it.  I have read the docs on this(all seem to be for a full symfony install, I am using twig only).

I think this article is on the right path but did not give me the information I needed to understand [Call PHP function from Twig template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665923/call-php-function-from-twig-template)

I do not get

1. where to put my php function? Can I just create a folder called extensions and put a navbar-list-funtion.php file in there?
2. where to register the function so it can be called from a template? some documentation say to register in the app/config/services.yml (I do not have this file or directory)
3. after I put the php function in a recognized place, then register it properly,... how will I call the returned array in the template navbar.html.twig?

Comment: If you are not using a framework like symfony, just follow the steps on the official [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#creating-an-extension)

Comment: thanks @darkbee, I have been and will continue to read the documentation. I just don't get it hence the reason I posted here.

Answer (score 2):

*from the comments*

If you are not using a framework like symfony, it's a bit flavor based on how you deal with this situation. Me, myself, i'm using namespaces in my project to enable autoloading with composer. My tree structure just follows my namespace e.g. `My/Project/Twig/Extensions`

The "best" way to extend `Twig` is by using a `Twig_Extension` class
Just place a new file in the folders you created with an appropriate name

---

**note:** As off Twig 2.X the function `getName()` is no longer mandator

<kbd>My/Project/Twig/Extensions/ProjectTwigExtension.twig</kbd>

```
namespace My/Project/Twig/Extensions

class ProjectTwigExtension extends Twig_Extension {

    public function getFunctions() {
        return array(
            new Twig_SimpleFunction('twig_function_name', array($this, 'getTwigFunctionName')),
            new Twig_SimpleFunction('twig_function_foo', array($this, 'getTwigFunctionFoo')),
            //and so on....,            
        );  
    }

    public function getFilters() {
        return array(
            new Twig_SimpleFilter('twig_filter_name' , array($this, 'getTwigFilterName')),
            new Twig_SimpleFilter('twig_filter_foo' , array($this, 'getTwigFilterFoo')),
            //and so on....,
        );
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'ProjectTwigExtension'; //this is mandatory for twig < 2.0
    }        
}
```

By using an extension class you can easily group all your functions/filters/nodes/globals/... After you created this class all you need to do is register the class inside `Twig`. As I don't know the specifics you will need  to look in your project where you do

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
```

To register the class just use the following line,

```
$twig->addExtension(new ProjectTwigExtension());
```

As you can the extension class has a function `getFunctions`, here you can define all the functions you want.

```
new Twig_SimpleFunction('twig_function_name', $callable)
```

The first argument defines how the function will be called inside a twig template, the second argument is a [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)

- `new Twig_SimpleFunction('twig_function_name', array($this, 'method'))`

  Will call the function `method` inside the current extension class
- `new Twig_SimpleFunction('twig_function_name', 'trim')`

  Will call the global function `trim`
- `new Twig_SimpleFunction('twig_function_name', array($obj, 'method'))`

  Will call the function `method` of the instance `$obj`
- `new Twig_SimpleFunction('twig_function_name', array('MyClass', 'method'))`

  Will call the static function `method` from `MyClass`
- `new Twig_SimpleFunction('twig_function_name', function($arg1, $arg2) { // ...; })`

  Will execute the closure

Comment: uggg, I think I will just deal with php include in each page I create.