# Default Twig Template Architecture

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I am trying to work on a project that uses `Twig Template`. Right now, I am learning it and have checked if I can do any alternate for the project as I know how the **MVC** architecture works. The `Twig Template` is different as it has file extension html.twig and the following in it:

```
{% for user in users %}
    <li>{{ user.username | e }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Now for alternate purpose, I've created a controller and view (Not using Twig rules) in the `Template` as follows that's very basic:

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
   //return something
}
```

**View:**

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   <p>This is a sample page.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I am not using the default architecture for the project (It works) and thinking not to use `Twig` architecture for the time being. So my question is if I can continue with raw `PHP` and basic `HTML` in the `Twig Template` architecture? Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the view files are being run through Twig, you won't be able to put any PHP statements inside them.

But you can certainly put plain HTML in Twig files, as you've found.

Comment: You got it right @tremby and was expecting this. Thanks but are you sure that I am unable to write PHP statements directly in the `Twig` file?

Comment: If it's running through the Twig interpreter, absolutely. It doesn't allow that. Here's a question about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665923/call-php-function-from-twig-template

Answer (score 1):

You can use php templating with our without `twig`

```
framework:
    # ...
    templating:
        engines: ['twig', 'php']
```

[Render controller](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/PHP.html#embedding-other-controllers) in php:

```
<?php echo $view['actions']->render(
    new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerReference(
        'App\Controller\HelloController::fancy',
        array(
            'name'  => $name,
            'color' => 'green',
        )
    )
) ?>
```