# How to call my custom function from my twig file in opencart 3.x

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I am calling a function in my controller file from my twig file, like I set my code as:

```
{% if myFunction('param1', 'param2') %}
    {{ 'do something' }}
{% endif %
```

}

But it giving this error.

Error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: Unknown "myFunction" function in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to access any PHP function inside Twig directly.

You should use the function to set a variable in your controller and then test the truth of that variable in Twig.

Or see this: [Call PHP function from Twig template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665923/call-php-function-from-twig-template)