# How to call functions inside a twig file?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Really new to symfony and I'm really confused...hoping to get some clarification here.

In my index.html.twig, I am trying to call a function called pinghosts
[Logic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJUwf.png).

Could someone please correct me and let me know how to call functions inside a twig file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call PHP function from Twig template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665923/call-php-function-from-twig-template)

Comment: First correction: don't use images in questions.

Comment: Look at @greeflas comment, you'll find the answer within it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would recommend reading  [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  on how to write a quality question. This helps for better understanding for the contributers.